# Importing common YAML in rstudio/knitr document

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

I have a few Rmd documents that all have the same YAML frontmatter except for the title. **How can I keep this frontmatter in one file and have it used for all the documents?** It is getting rather large and I don't want to keep every file in step every time I tweak the frontmatter.

I want to still

- use the Knit button/<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> shortcut in RStudio to do the compile
- keep the whole setup portable: would like to avoid writing a custom output format or overriding `rstudio.markdownToHTML` (as this would require me to carry around a `.Rprofile` too)

### Example

common.yaml:

```
author: me
date: "`r format (Sys.time(), format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z')`"
link-citations: true
reference-section-title: References
# many other options
```

an example document

```
----
title: On the Culinary Preferences of Anthropomorphic Cats
----

I do not like green eggs and ham. I do not like them, Sam I Am!
```

Desired output:
The compiled example document (ie either HTML or PDF), which has been compiled with the metadata in `common.yaml` injected in. The R code in the YAML (in this case, the date) would be compiled as a bonus, but it is not necessary (I only use it for the date which I don't really need).

### Options/Solutions?

I haven't quite got any of these working yet.

- With rmarkdown one can create a `_output.yaml` to put common YAML metadata, but this will put all of that metadata under `output:` in the YAML so is only good for options under `html_document:` and `pdf_document:`, and not for things like author, date, ...
- write a knitr chunk to import the YAML, e.g.

  ````
  ----
  title: On the Culinary Preferences of Anthropomorphic Cats
  ```{r echo=F, results='asis'}
  cat(readLines('common.yaml'), sep='\n')
  ```
  ----

  I do not like green eggs and ham. I do not like them, Sam I Am!
  ````

  This works if I `knitr('input.Rmd')` and then `pandoc` the output, but not if I use the Knit button from Rstudio (which I assume calls `render`), because this parses the metadata first before running knitr, and the metadata is malformed until knitr has been run.
- Makefile: if I was clever enough I could write a Makefile or something to inject `common.yaml` into `input.Rmd`, then run `rmarkdown::render()`, and somehow hook it up to the Knit button of Rstudio, and perhaps somehow save this Rstudio configuration into the `.Rproj` file so that the whole thing is portable without me needing to edit `.Rprofile` too. But I'm not clever enough.

**EDIT**: I had a go at this last option and hooked up a Makefile to the Build command (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>). However, this will build the same target every time I use it via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>, and I want to build the target that corresponds with the Rmd file I currently have open in the editor [as for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>].

Comment: Good question! "chunk"-ing in the .yaml seems especially problematic due to the `\`r format(...)\`` bits -- hard to know how R would tell it should recursively evaluate the code.

Comment: Yes, I thought that might be trouble. That's why I'd still be happy for a solution that did not parse R chunks in `common.yaml`.

Comment: There is [documentation](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/html_document_format.html#shared_options) out there for a reason.

Comment: @hrbrmstr I have already found this; it's the first thing I listed as (not) a solution in my question.

Comment: Turns out I seem to have only customized output in it (grepped through 2 years of them and they only have output customization in them). Carl's [makefile solution](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/297#issuecomment-61726038) may have some utility.

Comment: @hrbrmstr I have that listed as the third option in my question, but as stated, I'm not really clever enough (hence asking the question). I'm currently trying to learn Makefile syntax and think I can hook up the Makefile to the 'Build' command of Rstudio as opposed to the Knit one, but it's not my preferred choice.

Comment: Since the YAML gets turned into `knit`/`render` as parameters, you could probably invoke `knitr::opts_knit$set()` on a stored list of parameters. Alternately, just make your own template with `rmarkdown::output_format`, which is probably the sensible thing to do.

Comment: I was able to do this for myself by developing templates with all the information I needed, leading me to only put in the necessary variable info like the title or author. I basically followed [this guide by Chester Ismay](http://ismayc.github.io/ecots2k16/template_pkg/) to make a package, after seeing it in [this free coursera course](https://www.coursera.org/learn/reproducible-templates-analysis).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have found two options to do this portably (ie no `.Rprofile` customisation needed, minimal duplication of YAML frontmatter):

1. You can [provide common yaml to pandoc on the command-line](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/1960#issuecomment-242365453)! d'oh!
2. You can set the `knit:` property of the metadata to your own function to have greater control over what happens when you Ctrl+Shift+K.

## Option 1: common YAML to command line.

Put all the common YAML in its own file

`common.yaml`:

```
---
author: me
date: "`r format (Sys.time(), format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z')`"
link-citations: true
reference-section-title: References
---
```

Note it's complete, ie the `---` are needed.

Then in the document you can specify the YAML as the last argument to pandoc, and it'll apply the YAML (see [this github issue](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/1960#issuecomment-242365453))

in `example.rmd`:

```
---
title: On the Culinary Preferences of Anthropomorphic Cats
output:
  html_document:
    pandoc_args: './common.yaml'
---

I do not like green eggs and ham. I do not like them, Sam I Am!
```

You could even put the `html_document:` stuff in an `_output.yaml` since `rmarkdown` will take that and place it under `output:` for all the documents in that folder. In this way there can be **no** duplication of YAML between all documents using this frontmatter.

**Pros:**

- no duplication of YAML frontmatter.
- very clean

**Cons:**

- the common YAML is not passed through `knit`, so the date field above will not be parsed. You will get the literal string "r format(Sys.time(), format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z')" as your date.
- from the same github issue:

  > Metadata definitions seen first are kept and left unchanged, even if conflicting data is parsed at a later point.

Perhaps this could be a problem at some point depending on your setup.

## Option 2: override the `knit` command

This allows for much greater control, though is a bit more cumbersome/tricky.

[This link](https://github.com/lmmx/devnotes/wiki/Rmarkdown-custom-knit-hook-to-compile-a-multi-part-document) and [this one](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/277#issuecomment-59016672) mention an undocumented feature in rmarkdown: the `knit:` part of the YAML will be executed when one clicks the "Knit" button of Rstudio.

In short:

1. define a function `myknit(inputFile, encoding)` that would read the YAML, put it in to the RMD and call `render` on the result. Saved in its own file `myknit.r`.
2. in the YAML of `example.rmd`, add

   ```
    knit:  (function (...) { source('myknit.r'); myknit(...) })
   ```

   It seems to have to be on one line. The reason for `source('myknit.r')` instead of just putting the function definition int he YAML is for portability. If I modify `myknit.r` I don't have to modify every document's YAML. This way, the only *common* YAML that all documents must repeat in their frontmatter is the `knit` line; all other common YAML can stay in `common.yaml`.

Then Ctrl+Shift+K works as I would hope from within Rstudio.

Further notes:

- `myknit` could just be a system call to `make` if I had a makefile setup.
- the injected YAML will be passed through `rmarkdown` and hence knitted, since it is injected *before* the call to `render`.
- Preview window: so long as `myknit` produces a (single) message `Output created: path/to/file.html`, then the file will be shown in the preview window.

  I have found that there can be only **one** such message in the output [not multiple], or you get no preview window. So if you use `render` (which makes an "Output created: basename.extension") message and the final produced file is actually elsewhere, you will need to suppress this message via either `render(..., quiet=T)` or `suppressMessages(render(...))` (the former suppresses knitr progress and pandoc output too), and create your *own* message with the correct path.

**Pros:**

- the YAML frontmatter is knitted
- much more control than option 1 if you need to do custom pre- / post-processing.

**Cons:**

- a bit more effort than option 1
- the `knit:` line must be duplicated in each document (though by `source('./myknit.r')` at least the function definition may be stored in one central location)

---

Here is the setup for posterity. For portability, you only need to carry around `myknit.r` and `common.yaml`. No `.Rprofile` or project-specific config needed.

`example.rmd`:

```
---
title: On the Culinary Preferences of Anthropomorphic Cats
knit:  (function (...) { source('myknit.r'); myknit(...) })
---

I do not like green eggs and ham. I do not like them, Sam I Am!
```

`common.yaml` [for example]:

```
author: me
date: "`r format (Sys.time(), format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z')`"
link-citations: true
reference-section-title: References
```

`myknit.r`:

```
myknit <- function (inputFile, encoding, yaml='common.yaml') {   
    # read in the YAML + src file
    yaml <- readLines(yaml)
    rmd <- readLines(inputFile)

    # insert the YAML in after the first ---
    # I'm assuming all my RMDs have properly-formed YAML and that the first
    # occurence of --- starts the YAML. You could do proper validation if you wanted.
    yamlHeader <- grep('^---$', rmd)[1]
    # put the yaml in
    rmd <- append(rmd, yaml, after=yamlHeader)

    # write out to a temp file
    ofile <- file.path(tempdir(), basename(inputFile))
    writeLines(rmd, ofile)

    # render with rmarkdown.
    message(ofile)
    ofile <- rmarkdown::render(ofile, encoding=encoding, envir=new.env())

    # copy back to the current directory.
    file.copy(ofile, file.path(dirname(inputFile), basename(ofile)), overwrite=T)
}
```

Pressing Ctrl+Shift+K/Knit from the editor of `example.rmd` will compile the result and show a preview. I know it is using `common.yaml`, because the result includes the date and author whereas `example.rmd` on its own does not have a date or author.

Comment: The option 'preserve_yaml: true' exists to keep the yaml options in the Markdown document after knitr.

Answer (score 2):

The first solution proposed by [@mathematical.coffee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/913184/mathematical-coffee) is a good approach, but the example it gave did not work for me (maybe because the syntax had changed). As said so, this is possible by providing pandoc arguments in the YAML header. For example,

It's the content of a `header.yaml` file:

```
title: "Crime and Punishment"
author: "Fyodor Dostoevsky"
```

Add this to the beginning of the RMarkdown file:

```
---
output:
  html_document:
    pandoc_args: ["--metadata-file=header.yaml"]
---
```

[See the pandoc manual](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#option--metadata-file) for the `--metadata-file` argument.