# Multiple sets of Shared Options in R Markdown

Tags: r, knitr, pandoc, reveal.js

Is it possible to have multiple sets of shared options for R Markdown?

This is my problem: I have a folder with a bunch of markdown files. The files can be divided into two groups:

- `html_document` and
- `revealjs::revealjs_presentation`.

I would like to factor out common YAML code from each of these groups. Now I know that I can create a `_output.yaml` file which would capture common YAML, but I essentially need to have *two* of these files, one for each of the output formats.

I saw the use of `pandoc_args` suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39885363/importing-common-yaml-in-rstudio-knitr-document) and I gave it a try as follows:

```
---
title: Document Type 1
output:
  html_document:
    pandoc_args: './common-html.yaml'
---
```

and

```
---
title: Document Type 2
output:
  revealjs::revealjs_presentation:
    pandoc_args: './common-reveal.yaml'
---
```

However using this setup the options from the included YAML files don't get processed.

Any other suggestions would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can specify multiple *output formats* in the same `_output.yaml` file like this (just some example options):

```yaml
html_document:
  self_contained: false
revealjs::revealjs_presentation:
  incremental: true
```

Then you have to [render *all* output formats](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44689388/7196903) which cannot be done directly using the RStudio GUI. Instead you have to enter the following into the R console:

```r
rmarkdown::render(input = "your.Rmd",
                  output_format = "all")
```

Ideally make sure that there's no `output` key in the YAML front matter of the `.Rmd` document itself. Otherwise the output options in `_output.yaml` file might get overridden. Unfortunately I couldn't find a comprehensive documentation of the exact behavior. Some of my observations so far:

- Output options defined in the YAML front matter of the `.Rmd` document itself always [override those specified in the shared options file `_output.yaml`](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/html-document.html#shared-options).
- Specifying an output format using the default option set (like `pdf_document: default`) in the YAML front matter of the `.Rmd` document itself completely overrides all options specified in `_output.yaml`. But if you don't explicitly specify the default options (like `output: pdf_document`; which is only possible for a single output format at once), the `_output.yaml` content is fully regarded.
- If you have specified options for multiple output formats in `_output.yaml`, **only the first one gets rendered when pressing the knit button in RStudio** (even if you explicitly press `knit to HTML/PDF/Word`). You have to use `rmarkdown::render(output_format = "all")` to render the other formats, too.